# How to properly setup #define to make simple logger?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, c-preprocessor, nslog

How to correct `#define Log(str) NSLog(@"%@", str)`
for follow simple use this macros in code:

```
...
Log(Drew is man);
...
```

Comment: You're going to have to use `Log(@"Drew is man");`.  However this macro doesn't appear to add anything to `NSLog()` and removes the possibility of using a formatting string.

Comment: `#define Log(str) NSLog(@"" #str)` but such logging makes little sense to me...

Answer (score 1):

```
Please check below code it may help to you    
// Printing NSLog in only Debug mode or while using simulator only
    #if !defined(DEBUG) || !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)
    #define NSLog(...)
    #endif
```

Comment: Please add some description to your answer. Answers should not be code only.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for custom Log.

```
#define RKLog(x, ...) NSLog(x, ## __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: In this case I have to call RKLog(@"Drew is man") , but I want just call RKLog(Drew is man).